# Dropped Database Connections in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, tcpip, error-log

We are having an annoying intermittent problem where database connections from our client application on a variety of stations will get dropped.  We have applications that use ODBC, Borland Database Engine, and ADO and all get dropped.  When connections do get dropped, it isn't everyone - some remain connected while others get dropped.  Looking in the logs of one of the applications, I see messages like the following:

- TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired
- TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
- Query timeout expired
- TCP Provider: No such host is known

I don't see any error messages in the SQL error log or in the Windows events on either the client or the SQL Server.  Is there anyway to determine if this is a database or network issue from the SQL Server side of things?  For example, is there something I can turn on to monitor database connections and get reports when they are dropped?  This happens maybe once or twice a day but not at any specific time (not when backups run or something).

---

The issue seems to be network related and out of scope for this forum.

Comment: Ask your network guys if there are any TCP/IP idle timeouts set on the firewalls.

Comment: @GrumpyPhil: We don't have any firewalls between the clients and the SQL Server other than the Windows Firewall on the client themselves.

Comment: @Caynadian and is the behavior any different if you entirely shut that thing off? (In other words, this is certainly sounding like a network connectivity issue, not a database problem.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I have it shut off on one particularly problematic machine and it still occurs.  In fact, this machine (which is a VM running on VMware 5) experiences this issue more often than most though that might be because it runs 24-7 instead of just business hours.  Is there any SQL Server specific network monitoring tools you can think of?  I should note that the SQL Server is on a physical host and is not a VM.

Comment: It could be a physical problem with the cables.  We had a customer with similar complaints about our software.  Our IT guy flew to the customer location, replaced some Ethernet cables, and the problem went away.

Comment: @user1008646: I thought of that but the pattern of failures doesn't seem to indicate a cable failure.  I would think if the cable were bad that all connections would be dropped simultaneously.  It's still possible I guess but it seems unlikely.

Comment: I am going to use a small program I wrote to keep track of exactly when the failures occur on a few machines and see if I can get a better idea of what else is going on on the network at the same time.

Comment: This seems to be a network issue as @AaronBertrand indicated as I'm having ping time-outs to the DB.  I will close this question as it is unrelated to DB management.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score -1):

It can be SQL related, not just OS and hardware:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2491214

Comment: Chris, try to provide actual content and not just link answers.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for that but I didn't see any "non-yeilding" error messages in any of the logs.  Regardless, it seems to have been a hardware issue as the DB server RAID array crashed and since we have rebuilt the server on a new platform, we haven't had any issues.